# Преобразовать текст в ссылку

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Есть блок кода:

```
def print_hi():
    hyperlink_format = '<a href="{link}">{text}</a>'
    f = hyperlink_format.format(link='http://google.com', text='Hi')
    print(f)

который создает гиперссылку:
<a href="http://google.com">Hi</a>
```

как эту гиперссылку преобразовать в текстовую ссылку?

Чтобы слово " Hi " содержало в себе ссылку.

Пример:
[Hi](http://google.com)

P.S решение необходимо на python

Comment: что такое "текстовая ссылка"?

Comment: @strawdog текст который является ссылкой на какой-то сайт, например когда пользователь читает письмо и нажимает на слово (например ссылка), он переходит на сайт

Comment: Так гиперссылка и есть такая ссылка. Письмо, в котором есть ссылки - это и есть письмо в `html` формате. В чистом тексте нет никаких ссылок.

Comment: @CrazyElf как тогда мою сформированную гиперссылку вставить в письмо чтобы текст выглядел ссылкой?

Comment: @ВладиславЛинский Письмо должно быть в формате `html`. Когда вручную письмо в каком-нибудь `Outlook`-е посылаете, там можно переключать между `text` и `html` форматами. Я же не знаю, как вы посылаете письмо. В общем, нужно посылать в `html` формате.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


hyperlink_format = BeautifulSoup('<a href="{link}">{text}</a>'.format(link='http://google.com', text='Hi'))
```

Если я правильно понимаю, вам надо получить ссылку из текста, вот решение, но если она пойдет дальше, надо ее дорабатывать, и поставить аргумент

```
features="lxml
```

Comment: похоже, вы не дописали ответ. нажмите [edit] для редактирования.